# Controlling space between two markers relative to markersize

Tags: matplotlib

I have written a script that plots markers (X) over a ground plot of a building. Additionally I want to add colored points relatively to each of the markers, which works fine so far (like in the following image). I use the following code for plotting the points, as you can see i use the coordinates of the single markers and then place the points relative to the location of the X-markers.

```
plt.plot((((coordinates[i][1]-0.5*(j+1.8)))),(((coordinates[i][2]+0.5*(k-1)))),...)
```

However, what i would like to do is to place the points relatively to the X-markers not bei real coordinates but by x-times the marker size, like this:

```
plt.plot((((coordinates[i][1]-0.5*(j+markersize)))),(((coordinates[i][2]+0.5*(k-markersize)))),...)
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scaled transformation to plot the dots at the same position as the X-marker, but with an offset specified in units of the markersize.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def offsetpoint(x,y, px,py, msize, **kwargs):
    dx = px * msize/72.; dy = py * msize/72.
    to = matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation(dx,dy,fig.dpi_scale_trans)
    trans = ax.transData + to
    ax.plot(x,y, transform=trans, marker="o", ms=msize/4.7,**kwargs)

ms = 7
ax.plot([2],[3], ms=ms, marker="x",color="crimson")
offsetpoint([2],[3], -1,-0.5, ms, color="crimson")
offsetpoint([2],[3], -1,0 ,   ms, color="limegreen")
offsetpoint([2],[3], -1,0.5,  ms, color="gold")
offsetpoint([2],[3], -1.5,-0.5, ms, color="gold")
offsetpoint([2],[3], -1.5,0,    ms, color="limegreen")
offsetpoint([2],[3], -1.5,0.5,  ms, color="crimson")

ms = 15
ax.plot([1.5],[1.5], ms=ms, marker="x",color="mediumblue")
offsetpoint([1.5],[1.5], -1,-0.5, ms, color="darkviolet")
offsetpoint([1.5],[1.5], -1,0 ,   ms, color="turquoise")
offsetpoint([1.5],[1.5], -1,0.5,  ms, color="gold")
offsetpoint([1.5],[1.5], -1.5,-0.5, ms, color="darkviolet")
offsetpoint([1.5],[1.5], -1.5,0,    ms, color="limegreen")
offsetpoint([1.5],[1.5], -1.5,0.5,  ms, color="indigo")

ax.margins(x=0.5, y=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]